# Flask server not exiting when shutdown

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code, which is supposed to start the flask server up, run it for 10 seconds, and then shut it down.

If I start it, and let it run, it stops after the required 10 seconds.

However, if i fetch the page "`http://localhost:5000/companies`", the server will print the "exit 1" message after the 10 second timeout, but won't proceed any further until I fetch the page again. When I do that, the server exits.

It seems that after the first page it fetched, the server stops polling for requests and ignores the shutdown flag, and goes into blocking mode.

How can I correctly shut the server down?

```
import time
import threading

from flask import Flask

from werkzeug.serving import make_server

api = Flask("RestServer")

server = make_server("localhost", 5000, api)
thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)


def start():
    print ("start")
    thread.start()


def stop():
    print("exit 1")
    server.shutdown()
    print("exit 2")
    thread.join()
    print("exit 3")


@api.route('/companies', methods=['GET'])
def get_companies():
    return "OK"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
    time.sleep(10)
    stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `quit()` instead of shutdown

```
def stop():
    print("exit 1")
    quit()
    print("exit 2")
```

Comment: I can't simply quit the program, as there's a lot of processing to be done after I have stopped the server, and also quit() doesn't stop the program when you have other threads running.